# Time-out expires faster than expected - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis-7, web-config

I have a application that's working well, but, when i stay a short time without interactions at the page, the authentication goes down and return for the  login page. i'm trying to set it up  to 20 minutes or more on my web config.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="20" />
</authentication>

<sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
```

...

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
    <machineKey decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" />
```

on the app settings

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="2000" />
```

i saw everything in my ISS, tried to follow some steps that i found here and on microsoft community  but the session continues to expire faster than i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your SessionState `InProc`?  If it is, any recycling on your application pool will clear your session.  That could be caused by you rebuilding your application, as well as multiple settings in IIS.  I suggest you go with `StateServer` or `SQLServer` SessionState if you want your session to persist longer.

If you don't want to change your SessionState, look at the settings on your App Pool:

1. Open IIS
2. Choose Application Pools
3. Right click your application pool and select Advanced Settings
4. Find Idle Time-out (minutes) and increase to a bigger value.